# What role does God (the character) play post season five?

Tags: supernatural

AFAIK the original story arc ended in season five, before they started writing new material. All I remember is that there was some sort of conspiracy going on within the ranks of the angels and that Castiel was a 'rebel' so to speak and that 'God had left them.' Although this was toyed with when 'God' supposedly saved Dean in one episode. As I stopped watching after the fifth season ended, I can't really comment any further. Upon googling, I couldn't really seemed to find any information on whether or not they abandoned the concept or developed it further.

Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple references to God abandoning His post and leaving Heaven and the angels, but there haven't been any appearances or messages from Him as far as I can tell. Heaven has just been in turmoil and getting worse. I can't say too much more without revealing spoilers, of which there are many. The showrunners have kept a decent level of quality, even if not quite up to Eric Kripke's original story. All things considered, the show is still good with no definite end in sight without feeling overly soap-operatic.

God remains AWOL.

Comment: @remyabel Last season and this season are particularly centric to Heaven and the machinations of those who would control it in His absence. I'd recommend watching more. Considering you've seen the first five seasons, season six episode 15 "The French Mistake" is really fun in a "meta" kind of way.

Answer (score 1):

The show was originally supposed to run for five seasons, so the *official story arc* only covered those seasons. This is important as many fans speculate that God was in fact *Chuck Shurley*, the "prophet" from Season 5. Strong evidence of this theory (including the actor himself confirming it) can be [found here](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Chuck_Shurley#Is_Chuck_God.3F) and in the video:

Whilst this is certainly not definitive, it's fascinating. If Chuck was God, then they'd either need to bring the actor back or cast a new God. The former would be more likely, but ultimately neither is particularly needed. The show has dealt with heavy themes since Season 5, but nothing approaching the apocalypse or Lucifer Rising - meaning if God wasn't going to intervene then, it seems very unlikely (canon-wise) he would intervene now.

Ultimately though, though, God plays no role in the show after Season 5. We hear him being discussed and his apparent abandonment of Heaven used as a reason for the *many* revolts and rebellions that are being fought, from *[Raphael](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupernatural.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FRaphael&ei=Wah1VP_RKMqt7gaso4DYDQ&usg=AFQjCNEpjDm87QLm9eaDPMnrjE4DJuMfgw&bvm=bv.80642063,d.cWc)* trying to seize control, to *[Castiel](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupernatural.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FCastiel&ei=UKh1VPHlF-eE7ga-jIDQAw&usg=AFQjCNF3RQwufnKS1iayflT89W9WbLqL2g&bvm=bv.80642063,d.cWc)* trying to become more powerful, to *[Naomi](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupernatural.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FNaomi&ei=Rqh1VOGSBMWE7gbZ7IC4BQ&usg=AFQjCNH7WEq0QiwZHGH7Bi7D7joXuZpw0g&bvm=bv.80642063,d.cWc)* trying to reestablish control, to *[Metatron](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupernatural.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FMetatron&ei=PKh1VODTPLKd7ga3lYG4Cg&usg=AFQjCNEh32xBljboss157y8jhcz2YR94OQ&bvm=bv.80642063,d.cWc)* creating the *Great Fall*. The closest explanation we get is from Castiel, in the episode [Road Trip](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Road_Trip), where he discusses the angel [Gadreel](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Gadreel), who allowed Lucifer into the Garden of Eden. Castiel says:

> **CASTIEL** It's his fault -- all of it. The corruption of man, demons,
>   hell. ***God left because of him.*** The archangels -- the apocalypse. If he
>   hadn't been so weak, none of it would have happened.

In short - God is very much AWOL. He may or may not appear in the series (it hasn't been confirmed) or indeed, he may have *already appeared* if you believe the Chuck Shurley theories.

Comment: I guess they dropped a bridge on [him](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DroppedABridgeOnHim). I recently finished the remaining seasons and they completely took the angel arc in a different direction. It's unfortunate.

Comment: @remyabel: I think they wanted to just wrap up the storyline as they *originally* wanted to convey it. Everything from Season 6 onwards was never originally intended, so is sadly *smaller scale* than Seasons 4 and 5.

Comment: @remyabel: And I've definitely found the angels to be a little disappointing as time has gone on (except for Castiel, who rocks it)